# How do I add a multi guild thing in Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm working on this mute code:

```
if (cmd === "mute") {
      if (
        message.member.permissions.has(
          "ADMINISTRATOR",
          "KICK_MEMBERS",
          "BAN_MEMBERS",
          "MANAGE_ROLES"
        )
      ) {
        const target = message.mentions.members.first();
        if (target) {
          let mainRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(
            (role) => role.name === "{}Scouts (VERIFIED)"
          );
          let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(
            (role) => role.name === "Muted"
          );

          let memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
          // timer mute
          if (!args[1]) {
            memberTarget.roles.remove(mainRole.id);
            memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole.id);
            message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been muted`);
            return;
          }
          // manually mute
          memberTarget.roles.remove(mainRole.id);
          memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole.id);
          message.channel.send(
            `<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been muted for ${ms(ms(args[1]))}`
          );

          setTimeout(function () {
            memberTarget.roles.remove(muteRole.id);
            memberTarget.roles.add(mainRole.id);
          }, ms(args[1]));
        } else {
          message.channel.send(" I can't mute this member !");
        }
      } else {
        message.channel.send("You can't mute members !");
      }
    }
```

I'm trying to make it so that I won't have to keep changing

```
let mainRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find( (role) => role.name === "{}Scouts (VERIFIED)" )"
```

instead, I'm trying to make this work on multiple servers/guilds without having to change it. How can I achieve that?

Comment: FYI, I wouldn't search for a role by using it's name, as these can change which might break your bot. Use the ID instead.

Answer (score 1):

You may check if the role exists in that guild if it doesn't create one!

```js
if(!muteRole) {
const muteRole = 
message.guild.roles.create({
  data: {
    name: "Muted",
  },
  reason: 'Creating Mute role',
});
message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(async (channel, id) => {
             await channel.createOverwrite(muteRole, {
                SEND_MESSAGES: false,
                MANAGE_MESSAGES: false,
                READ_MESSAGES: false,
                ADD_REACTIONS: false
             });
          });
memberTarget.roles.set([]); // removed all roles 
memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole.id);
return message.channel.send("Mute role not found! Created Muted Role and muted user ");
}
```

This would allow your bot to create a role if none is present in that guild and the `GuildMemberRolesManager#set([])` would remove all the roles from the user so you don't have to remove "specific" roles each time!

Comment: Hey ! So I tried this yesterday and for some reason it just didn't work, there was no response that it made a mute role and it didn't mute the member ( when I created a mute role for it )

Also, Is there a way I can set a timer? Like `mute @user 10m` ? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks !

Comment: Of course it won't respond if there's already a mute role, I added the answer in a case there's no mute role you have to use your own code with my current answer, the timer based thingy can be done using a database, consider switching to one!

Comment: I'm already connected to a database, MongoDB to be exact, but I'm running into multiple errors now, it's saying `ReferenceError: muteRole is not defined`, apologies on asking so many questions, thank you for your patience !

Comment: ```let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(
            (role) => role.name === "Muted"``` you defined it right here yourself, also if you're connected to MongoDB look up how you can create timed mutes you'd need a proper schema for it n stuff, can go complicated, if you have further queries please contact me on discord I'm 0_0#6666 you may also contact me by joining my server [here](https://discord.gg/ZeroSync)